# UIPageViewControllerDelegate previousViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

Do you know any scenarios when

`pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:`

returns multiple    previousViewControllers

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple guide about [UIPageViewControllerDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerDelegateProtocolRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPageViewControllerDelegate/pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:)
`previousViewControllers`:The view controllers prior to the transition.
When you scroll at that time this delegate invokes,just scroll little and add breakpoint at this method and test your scenario